# How to best initialise state / set first state in React / Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

For now I am doing the following in my reducer:

```
export default function (state = null, action) {

    if(state==null)
    {
        state = [
            {
                id: 1,
                first: "Bucky",
                last: "Roberts",
                age: 71,
                description: "Bucky is a React developer and YouTuber",
                thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/7yUvePI.jpg"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                first: "Joby",
                last: "Wasilenko",
                age: 27,
                description: "Joby loves the Packers, cheese, and turtles.",
                thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/52xRlm8.png"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                first: "Madison",
                last: "Williams",
                age: 24,
                description: "Madi likes her dog but it is really annoying.",
                thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/4EMtxHB.png"
            }
        ]
    }

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'USER_DELETED':
            return state.filter(user => user.id !== action.userIdToDelete);
    }

    return state;
}
```

So I check whether state is null, and if it is I populate it. Is there a better way to do this, i.e. to not populate my reducer from within? Looks like bad practice to me...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a default value of it to null - do the following

```
        initialState = [
        {
            id: 1,
            first: "Bucky",
            last: "Roberts",
            age: 71,
            description: "Bucky is a React developer and YouTuber",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/7yUvePI.jpg"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            first: "Joby",
            last: "Wasilenko",
            age: 27,
            description: "Joby loves the Packers, cheese, and turtles.",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/52xRlm8.png"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            first: "Madison",
            last: "Williams",
            age: 24,
            description: "Madi likes her dog but it is really annoying.",
            thumbnail: "http://i.imgur.com/4EMtxHB.png"
        }
    ];

    export default function (state = initalState, action) {
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always set the default state value to the type that you expect it to be, so here `function (state=[])` is better. Setting it to null is an anti-pattern.

Then as for data as default initial state you should use the second argument in createStore to set the initial state: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html

Comment: thanks. however, my second argument is `applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, logger)` is this incorrect then?

Comment: Your apply middleware becomes your third argument when you include initial (preloaded) state. 

So, in the link I sent createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer]), the enhancer is your middleware.